# Skin Detection and Background Subtraction in Python cv2

Tags: python, opencv, gesture-recognition

For the past couple of days, I've been working on a gesture recognition program using OpenCV Python.  Ideally, I'd like to have a system like the one shown in [this video](https://youtu.be/xML2S6bvMwI?list=PLtszSfeV_ZqjcPArVX1PU68Vv4qRBVVnw).  I've read through the algorithm described in the video description, and I understand just about all of it.  However, I have been having trouble replicating his success in background subtraction and skin tone detection.  All of my attempts have ended up very noisy and/or very lighting-dependent, both of which render my code useless for the time being.

I have tried the following:

- BackgroundSubtractorMOG and BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 applied to color frame
- Split image into Y Cr Cb, applied MOG or MOG2 to each before recombining into a single image
- Filter range to remove colors that aren't skin tones (applied to color image)

So far, I have not had success.  I have been able to pick out some contours, but these have been noisy and unstable (come and go depending on the frame).  Is their another approach I should be using?

Comment: One of beautiful background subtraction that i found is this one http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/25/basic-motion-detection-and-tracking-with-python-and-opencv/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have written a [fingerspelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerspelling) interpreter application, so I've encountered many of the robustness issues you're facing.  After several weeks of experimentation, I settled on a solution that incorporated a few different approaches, but the most important approach employed was color-based segmentation.

Color-based (skin tone) segmentation can be very powerful, but a simplistic implementation is bound to lack the robustness you're looking for.  First of all, everyone's skin color is different.  So it's important to identify the baseline skin color through some other mechanism.  One approach is to use a face detector (such as a cascade classifier) to find the subject's face, and then "tune" the filter ranges accordingly.

I personally used a cascade classifier to first find the closed fist shape, and then I normalized and differenced the HSV histograms between 1) a tight bounding box only including the fist and 2) the entire image.  Then I set up a lookup table (LUT) mapping each value for each channel to a value between 0 and 255 representing the probability that the pixel represents skin.

In my experience, the *most* important factor that improved the performance of my hand tracking logic was when I struck on the idea of not throwing away information.  You will be tempted to simply threshold using some optimal ranges in order to generate a binary image, but there is value in knowing that one pixel has a 40% chance of being skin and another has a 60% chance.  Once you threshold, all you have is a 1 and a 0.

Of course, if you intend to use contour-based classification of poses, it may be necessary to threshold at some point.  But if you really want to build robust gesture recognition software, you may want to investigate using a [Convolutional Neural Net (CNN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) to perform the classification.  Prediction can be done very quickly, and it's very robust to background noise, translation, etc...  Hope this helps!

EDIT: Let me clarify my comments about "normalizing and differencing the HSV histograms".  First of all, the rationale for doing this is to be able to make use of OpenCV's [LUT (lookup table)](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#lut) rather than using range-based thresholding.  `LUT` is very efficient, and is more flexible than range-based thresholding.  For example, suppose the hue that you want includes values in two separate ranges (e.g.: 0-30 and 150-180).  A LUT-based approach easily deals with that since each individual value can be mapped independently.

So once you establish the LUT, you only need to run `LUT` on the HSV image for each frame.  It's a very efficient solution.

In my case, to build the LUT, I took the following steps:

- Convert to HSV color space.
- Get the ROI of the tight bounding box around the fist.
- Build histograms for each channel for both the ROI and the entire image.
- Scale down (normalize) the full image channel histograms so that scale matches that of the ROI histograms (i.e.: multiply each full image histogram by ROI_area/full_image_area).
- Subtract (difference) the full image histograms from the ROI histograms.  (Entries with large positive values will correspond to channel values commonly found in the ROI, but not the full image.)
- I then smooth the difference histograms to reduce noise and "overfitting".
- Finally, I normalize the difference histograms to values between 0.0 and 1.0 using OpenCV's `normalize` function with `NORM_MINMAX`.
- The difference histograms can then just be merged together to produce a 3-channel LUT.

I personally don't threshold the values after using the LUT.  Instead, I just use the resulting data to compute a "center of color mass" of sorts which I use to keep a ROI centered on the hand.  Then, I can send the same LUT-based values to a CNN for classification.

Note that while this approach works well for my purposes, if you do perform thresholding, it's still not going to be perfect; there will be some foreground detected as background and vice versa.  I incorporated some edge detection-based logic to help reduce false positives resulting from beige walls (a common failure mode in my house), but the reality is that if there's a truly robust way to cleanly segment a hand from the background that's truly robust to changing backgrounds and lighting conditions, I haven't found it.  So my recommendation is to take a cue from the visual cortex and allow information from higher levels of abstraction to help filter out the noise.  (In other words, investigate CNNs - they're truly remarkable.)

Comment: So far, I've selected a test region (a closed fist for now, based on your suggestion) and generated an HSV histogram based on the H and S channels.  However, I'm not too sure what you mean be normalizing and differencing the histograms between the two images.  I've attempted to equalize the fist histogram and backproject it to the original image, but I'm still seeing issues with some skin missed and some other objects detected as skin.  Was your technique able to avoid this?

Comment: I've added some further clarifications - please see my edits.

Comment: Okay, I've managed to generate, normalize, and difference the histograms, but I'm having trouble creating the lookup table.  I've looked around, but I can't seem to find a good explanation on how to create an HSV lookup table like I need.  I tried this code `LUT = cv2.merge((difference_hists[0], difference_hists[1], difference_hists[2]))` where difference_hists stores the differenced histograms for the H, S, and V channels in indices 0, 1, and 2, respectively.  However, this keeps giving me an error whenever I run it:

Comment: `LUT = cv2.merge((difference_hists[0], difference_hists[1], difference_hists[2]))
error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\convert.cpp:296: error: (-215) mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth in function cv::merge`

Comment: Check out the `merge` documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=merge#cv2.merge).  The array of input matrices are passed as one parameter.  So you probably want something more like: `LUT = cv2.merge(difference_hists)`.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried that, but I'm still getting the same error.  I also tried padding `difference_hists[0]` with zeros to make it the same length as `difference_hists[1]` and `difference_hists[2]`, but still no luck.  Also, how are you smoothing histograms?  I tried the `cv2.equalize` function, but that's throwing an error as well.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now - using HSV implies that the first histogram (for hue) will only have 180 elements...  I looked back at my code, and I actually switched to using the YCrCb color space, so I didn't run into that issue.  You could switch to YCrCb.  Otherwise, you'd have to post some code - I'm not sure why you'd still get an error if you're ensuring that all the histograms have the same shape.  Regarding the smoothing, I used the [blur](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=blur#cv2.blur) function.

Comment: Okay, I switched to the YCrCb colorspace, and I have a working LUT.  However, the LUT creates an image where the probability of a pixel containing skin is represented by a color from dark-purple to blue-white.  Is there a way to represent this range as being from black to white?  (Am I using it right? `skin = cv2.LUT(img, LUT)`)  Also I've been having trouble equalizing histograms.  Every single histogram I true (regardless of whether it's from the original image or after differencing), I get the same error: `error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function equalizeHist`

Comment: The LUT function is returning a 3 channel matrix, so if you want a grayscale image, you need to split it into the 3 channels, combine them (e.g.: multiply them together to produce a "master" probability matrix), and then normalize it to the desired range (e.g.: use `normalize` with range 0.0 to 255.0 and `NORM_MINMAX` type).  Regarding `equalizeHist`, the error is telling you that the src parameter is not an 8-bit single channel image as required.  I'm not sure why that would be the case - your histograms should have the appropriate type and depth.  But I wouldn't recommend equalizing anyway.

Comment: Okay, pretty much everything is working right now.  My processing function produces a nice grayscale image that I can work with.  I just have one last question.  Is there a specific function you were using to smooth the histograms, as you described in the third to last step?  I've tried `cv2.equalizeHist` with no success, and was wondering if you used a different function/algorithm for this step.

Comment: I was using [blur](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=blur#cv2.blur) on each differenced histogram.  In Python, it would probably look like: `difference_hists[i] = cv2.blur(difference_hists[i], (1, smooth_factor))` where `smooth_factor` is some relatively small value.  I wound up settling on 7 I think.  It's possible that a gaussian blur might produce better results - I didn't really experiment much with different smoothing functions.

Comment: Alright, I modified my code to smooth the histograms before being normalized.  The script is working pretty well now, I should be able to move on to gesture tracking pretty soon.  I may take a look at convolutional neural networks for more advance gesture recognition.  Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

Background subtraction tends to leave a lot of ghost images.You should start with HSV based skin detection, to rule out the non skin regions. This will eliminate the need for background subtraction.

Then you can apply face detection to mask out your face, following which, when you're left with only the hand contours, you can use approxPolyDP() to get a simplified polygon. Computing the moments and convexity of this polygon will give you a base for gesture recognition